# Unbind a scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After 5 seconds when a user scrolls to a specific section of a page, I'm collapsing a module (with Bootstrap). The problem is when you manually click the button to collapse again, this function still fires and I don't want that behavior.

Basically I want this function to fire only once after the user scrolls to that specific element on the page. How would I go about doing that?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $('#whatsNextGhost');
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    var collapseAccordion = function() {
        if (scroll > objectPosition) {
            $('#whatsNextSectionContent').collapse('hide');
        }
    };

    setTimeout(collapseAccordion, 5000);
});
```

Comment: `$(window).off('scroll')`?

Comment: I actually tried something like this: `$('#whatsNextButton').on('click', function () { $(window).off('scroll'); });` but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a little fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/1j790jxb/

On scroll I simply log something to the console:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
  console.log('scroll attached');
});
```

When I hit a button (with ID button) I detach the scroll:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(event){
  $(window).off('scroll');
});
```

As you can see in the Fiddle: after you click the button, nothing appears in the console anymore.

You might also want to take a look at: namespacing your (scroll) event and requestAnimationFrame:

- https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/
- https://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign window to a variable so that it disengages the listener from the same instance of "window" you applied it to since your off handler is in a different context if it outside of the initializing closure.

ie:

```
$window = $('window');

$window.on('scroll', function(){
    var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
    var objectSelect = $('#whatsNextGhost');
    var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
    var collapseAccordion = function() {
        if (scroll > objectPosition) {
            $('#whatsNextSectionContent').collapse('hide');
        }
    };

    setTimeout(collapseAccordion, 5000);
});

$window.off('scroll') // this goes inside whatever method you are using to remove the listener.
```

Edit: grammar